# ng-style with scope variables in AngularJS 1.4.8

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-scope

index.html:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="app" ng-style="{ color: thecolor }">
  foo
</div>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("app", function() {
    $scope.thecolor = "red";
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvyyLwsk/).

Expected: "foo" is rendered red. Observed: "foo" is rendered black (the default).

So basically I'm trying to set the style of an element from variables in the scope. I've seen this working in Angular 1.0.2, but I need it to work in 1.4.8.

**EDIT:** Once I've updated the controller to include the `$scope` dependency, I still can't get certain things to work, such as positioning within a parent element.

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css">
<script src="app.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="app">
  <div ng-style="{ left: x, top: y }">
    foo
  </div>
</div>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("app", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.x = 100;
    $scope.y = 100;
}]);
```

app.css:

```
body {
  margin: 0px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

div div {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Expected: "foo" is rendered 100px down and to the right. Observed: no displacement.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hvyyLwsk/2/).

Comment: Simple error, you forgot to include `$scope` in your controller dependencies. https://jsfiddle.net/hvyyLwsk/1/

Comment: Please see my updated problem statement above.

Comment: You need the "px" suffix for your `left` and `top` values.

Comment: Shoot, I tried that in the html file, and had no success, but it looks like changing `x` and `y` to strings with "px" appended works. Is there any way to specify "px" in the view?

Comment: Looks like it works if I do something like `ng-style="{ left: x + 'px', top: y + 'px' }"`. If you write up your response as an answer, I'll accept it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the unit for the CSS values - you can do it in the view:

```
<div ng-style="{ left: x + 'px', top: y + 'px' }">
```

Answer (score 2):

Controller in your code doesnt have $scope as Dependency Injection (DI), based on your updated question modifying the answer as below

**controller**

```
angular.module("app", [])
 .controller("app", ['$scope',function($scope) {
    $scope.thecolor = "red";
    $scope.x = 100;
    $scope.y = 100;
}]);
```

**view**

```
 <div ng-style="{ left: x + 'px', top: y + 'px' }">foo</div>
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nfdoqbg0/)

Comment: @BrianGradin updated the answer as per your latest requiement

Answer (score 0):

You missed `$scope` injection in controller.

```
angular.module("app", [])
.controller("Ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.thecolor = "red";
});
```

Here is a working demo:

http://jsbin.com/jomacoj/edit?html,js,console,output